# How to set column length to "max" in typeorm postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am new to typeorm. I want to set the length of a column to "MAX".

Here is what I've tried:

```
@Entity('InboundCallConfig')
export class InboundCallConfigEntity{
    @Index()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    Id: number;

    @Column( { nullable: true , length: 200 })
    CallerId: string;

    @Column( { type: "varchar", length:"MAX" } )
    WebhookUrl :string;

    @Column( { type:"varchar", length: 100, nullable:true})
    HTTPMethod: string;

    @Column( {default: false} )
    IsDeleted: boolean;
}
```

but when I try to run my program it got an error saying :

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to not specify a length at all? Or simply use `text`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation of [typeorm](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entities) it only accepts number type value for length property :

```
@Column({
    type: "varchar",
    length: 150,
    unique: true,
    // ...
})
name: string;

length: number - Column type's length. For example if you want to create varchar(150) type you specify column type and length options.
```

Also mysql server version is important because some versions don't support `MAX` syntax on length property and some has restrictions on string byte size of a column .